# Residue of $\frac{z}{1-\cos(z)}$ at $z= 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've managed so far to find the Laurent Series Expansion at $0$ and I have this:
$\frac{2}{z} - \frac{z}{6} + \frac{z^3}{120} + O(z^5)$

We know that the residue is the $a_{-1}$ term of the series $\sum_{ n = -m}{a_nz^n}$  so I guess it should be in $\frac{2}{z} - \frac{z}{6}$ but I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: $\frac{2}{z} = 2z^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Laurent series of your function centered at $0$ has that form. Therefore, the residue of the function at $0$ is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$, which is $2$.

Comment: It looks like 2 to me.

Comment: @Gribouillis Sure! I've edited my answer. Thank you.